# PlutusV2: Error when spending script output

Tags: plutus, datum, plutus-v2, plutus-apps, emulator

This is how I spend script's utxos with the Emulator. This one [from this example](https://github.com/Vortecsmaster/EmurgoAcademyPlutusExamples/blob/d4253139843b504d7237dc9fb050f676b730283a/V1/JustValidators/src/AlwaysSucceedandFail.hs#L81).

```
grab :: forall w s e. AsContractError e => Contract w s e ()  
grab = do
  utxos <- utxosAt scrAddress                                                                      
  let orefs   = fst <$> Map.toList utxos                                                           
    lookups = Constraints.unspentOutputs utxos <>                                           
              Constraints.plutusV1OtherScript validator                                          
    tx :: TxConstraints Void Void                                                            
    tx      = mconcat [mustSpendScriptOutput oref $ Redeemer $ Builtins.mkI 17 | oref <- orefs]  
                                                                                                 
  ledgerTx <- submitTxConstraintsWith @Void lookups tx                                             
  void $ awaitTxConfirmed $ getCardanoTxId ledgerTx                                                
  Plutus.Contract.logInfo @String $ "collected gifts"
```

This is PlutusV1. This works as expected. But [with PlutusV2](https://github.com/Vortecsmaster/EmurgoAcademyPlutusExamples/blob/d4253139843b504d7237dc9fb050f676b730283a/V2/JustValidators/src/AlwaysSucceedandFailV2.hs#L80), the `lookups` now is like:

```
    lookups = Constraints.unspentOutputs utxos <>                                           
              Constraints.plutusV2OtherScript validator
```

Note the version difference in `Constraints.plutusV2OtherScript validator`.

The rest of the code is the same except that this time the package is plutus-apps v1.0.0.

The V2 script compiles but when `grab` is called I get this error:

> *** CONTRACT STOPPED WITH ERROR: ""ConstraintResolutionContractError (DatumNotFound
> 03170a2e7597b7b7e3d84c05391d139a62b157e78786d8c082f29dcf4c111314)""

I try `Constraints.otherScript (Versioned validator PlutusV2)`. Same error.

I try `Plutus.Trace` instead of `Plutus.Trace.Emulator`. Same error.

This is just one example. I see this "DatumNotFound" error in other projects when trying to work with plutus-apps v1.0.0.

How do I fix this. Or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The cause is `mustPayToOtherScript` in the `give` [endpoint](https://github.com/Vortecsmaster/EmurgoAcademyPlutusExamples/blob/d4253139843b504d7237dc9fb050f676b730283a/V1/JustValidators/src/AlwaysSucceedandFail.hs#L74) where

```
give :: AsContractError e => Integer -> Contract w s e ()
give amount = do
  let tx = mustPayToOtherScript valHash (Datum $ Builtins.mkI 0) $ Ada.lovelaceValueOf amount 
  ledgerTx <- submitTx tx                                                                         
  void $ awaitTxConfirmed $ getCardanoTxId ledgerTx                                                
  Plutus.Contract.logInfo @String $ printf "made a gift of %d lovelace" amount
```

The error is fixed by replacing `mustPayToOtherScript` with `mustPayToOtherScriptWithDatumInTx`.

Get the answer [from mlabs-haskell/plutip](https://github.com/mlabs-haskell/plutip/blob/7f2d59abd911dd11310404863cdedb2886902ebf/test/Spec/TestContract/AlwaysFail.hs#L45). Thanks to their warning:

> -- WARN: at the moment 'mustPayToOtherScript' causes 'DatumNotFound' error during constraints resolution